# Program to generate primes not working

Tags: javascript, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I made the following code to generate an array of primes till a number 'num'.
But It is giving totally unexpected results.
I tried debugging it on chrome but the debugger does not help much as it just skips over the 4th line.

```js
function Sieve(num) {
  var arr =  Array.from({length:num-1}).map((x,i)=> i+2);
  var numb = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num));
  var arra = Array.from({length:numb-1}).map((x,i)=> i+2);
  arra.forEach(x => arr = arr.filter(y => ((y%x)!==0)||(y=!x)));
  console.log(arr);
}
Sieve(10)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `numb` and `arra`?

Comment: @Hassan numb is used to generate arra

Comment: @Hassan arra is used because we have to check it's divisibilty only till numb not after that. Check this  out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this supposed to be Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm? Just to mention, you know this is not the fastest way to generate primes?

**[Bersteins's primegen](http://cr.yp.to/primegen.html) is confirmed faster, and they might be even faster solutions.**

That aside, let's display simple code for what you are trying to achieve:

```
var eratosthenes = function(n) {
// Eratosthenes algorithm to find all primes under n
var array = [], upperLimit = Math.sqrt(n), output = [];

// Make an array from 2 to (n - 1)
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    array.push(true);
}

// Remove multiples of primes starting from 2, 3, 5,...
for (var i = 2; i <= upperLimit; i++) {
    if (array[i]) {
        for (var j = i * i; j < n; j += i) {
            array[j] = false;
        }
    }
}

// All array[i] set to true are primes
for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if(array[i]) {
        output.push(i);
    }
}

return output;
};
```

This is far simpler to understand and split in sections.

BTW, you know `Array.from(new Array(n-1), (x,i) => i+2);` works? There is no need to `array.from()` and then `.map()`, you can pass map function directly into from as a parameter. Also with new Array(n) code is a bit more readable.

This is solution using your principles.

```
function Sieve(num) {
  var arra =  Array.from(new Array(num-1), (x,i) => i+2);
  var comb = Array.from(new Array(Math.sqrt(num)-1), (x,i) => 2+i);

  comb.forEach(x => arra=arra.filter(y => (y%x !== 0) || (y===x) ));
  console.log(arra);
}
Sieve(100);
```

It's on CodePen since JSFiddle breaks. [labda solution to Erathostene's sieve](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MryJYM?editors=1011)

Comment: Even I could have made my code simpler by using loops. But I don't wan't to use them. But thanks for that algorithm I will check it out.

Comment: I thought you just wanted a simple solution, but I guess you are trying to use lambdas. Well, then a quick tip - from can accept map function as a parameter, no need to chain them. Also, by creatign new array with new Array(n) code is far mroe readable then by doing so from length object. At least to me. how did you come to know that it works with length object?

Comment: I don't remember where I saw that 'length' one but I like your method so will use it from next time.

Comment: I have fixed upon your code and I get good result, problem is console.log is not working. If you put a breakpoint in last console.log and look at the array it is what is to be expected, a solution. Problem is I don't know why it's not logging. Also, I broke up lambdas into callbacks so it's easier to debug. https://jsfiddle.net/r1bubaq2/

Comment: It works in codepen, added the link. Open up CodePen console, edit a char and it will autorun.

Comment: @ChiefVOLDEMORT Found a solution that I think would please you. I changed last lambdas so array gets updated from filter on each number of the comb. Also, comb is now from 2 to root of n.

Comment: But there is an bug in your code. Prime numbers below sqrt(num) are not logged.

Comment: Also I found the problem in my code I just had to replace the '!' with '=' in 4th line.It should be x==y.  Anyway thanks for your solutions

Comment: You are right. Glad to be of help, interesting approach you presented there ;)